# Compiling issue for target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am tying to compile but getting the above error. Basically this is what I have.

```
java.lang.Object obj = Account::getTestaccount;
```

The Account is a class which has TestAccount object declared with setter and getter methods.

Could someone please tell me why this is throwing an error.Thanks.

Comment: is `Object` a functional interface?

Comment: No its just the  java.lang.Object class

Comment: As the error states, `java.lang.Object` is not a [functional interface](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces). as a matter of fact, it's not even an interface. it's the base class of all classes in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target type of a lambda expression or a method reference **must** be a [functional interface](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces) i.e. *any interface with a SAM(Single Abstract Method)*.

Your code is not working because `java.lang.Object` is not a functional interface.

Looking at the code snippet you've provided it seems that you're looking for a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) functional interface or a specific specialization of a `Supplier`.

`Java 8` provides a rich family of Functional interfaces which can be found here :  [package java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: well you can do `Object j = (Function<String, Integer>) String::length;` for example

Comment: @Eugene true, but you should avoid doing such things unless _absolutely necessary_.